# Initialize device on port using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaCAV.png)I have a Verifone vx805 device connected to a linux machine running Debian 9 (64 bit). This device is controlled by a xml API that gets initialized like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Esp:Interface Version="1.0" xmlns:Esp="http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/"><Esp:Admin TerminalId="Term1234" Action="INIT" /></Esp:Interface>
```

Now the problem i am having is that i tried to query this api using Postman and there is no response from it. It is supposed to respond in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Esp:Interface Version="1.0" xmlns:Esp="http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/"><Esp:Admin Action="INIT" ActionCode="APPROVE" MessageReasonCode="9791" TerminalId="Term1234"></Esp:Admin></Esp:Interface>
```

I then wrote a small Nodejs server to try and initialize using code as follows:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

const axios = require('axios');

app.post('/init-device', async (req, res, next) => {
    const config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' }
    };
    const bodyXml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Esp:Interface Version="1.0" xmlns:Esp="http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/">
        <Esp:Admin TerminalId="LINUX001" Action="INIT" />
    </Esp:Interface>`;

    let result = await axios.post('http://localhost:23001', bodyXml, config);
    res.send(result.data);

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

I then used Thunder-client after running the app to run *localhost:3000/init-device* as a POST request but i still get the un-ending "Sending request" response.

Now, I have a java app that successfully initializes this device so I used that to send commands to the device whilst sniffing packets with *tcpdump* like this *sudo tcpdump -vv -x -X -s 1500 -i lo 'port 23001' -w /home/gyron/eft_stuff* for analysis with *wireshark*. From the analysis, I took out the hex stream of the packets and converting back to Ascii, I found out that the packets have some funny preceding characters like so:

```
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
```

[Initialize device command as seen in Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EXVT.png)

My question now is how do I make my Nodejs code run that as the *bodyXml* to the port and get the terminal to initialize? Is there another way of initializing the terminal besides what i am trying to do? The terminal listens on port 23001 on localhost

EDIT: Results after using net.Socket

```
const net = require('net');

const rawData = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Esp:Interface Version=\"1.0\" xmlns:Esp=\"http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/\"><Esp:Admin TerminalId=\"LINUX001\" Action=\"INIT\"><Esp:Register Type=\"CALLBACK\" EventId=\"DATA_REQUIRED\" /><Esp:Register Type=\"EVENT\" EventId=\"DEBUG_ALL\" /></Esp:Admin></Esp:Interface>';
var uint8array = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(rawData);
var mString = new TextDecoder().decode(uint8array);
const port = 23001;

const client = net.createConnection({ port: port }, () => {
  // 'connect' listener.
  console.log('connected to server!');
  client.write(mString);
});
client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('remote sent:', data.toString());
  client.end();
});

client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

Above is the code that i use. I have dumped the packets to port 23001 and now comparing the packets with wireshark i get the following (top packet works whilst the bottom packet, sent from my nodejs code does not work)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the TCP/IP headers of your packet. The payload of this packet is XML. Don't worry, even when sending from Node.js or Postman, this TCP/IP header is there for sure - you can dump it as well. In Wireshark you can select to decode only the TCP stream in which case you will see the data without the headers.

In order to send 'raw' data, you need to use `net.Socket` - check it in the Node.js documentation

```js
const net = require('net');
const client = net.createConnection({ port: PORT }, () => {
  // 'connect' listener.
  console.log('connected to server!');
  client.write(rawData);
});
client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('remote sent:', data.toString());
  client.end();
});
client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

Comment: Oh ok, i get that. Now, would you have any idea why Postman and Nodejs do not manage to get a response from the device whereas with java i can do that easily?

Comment: It is not the language/framework, it is the data. Dump the network output of your Node.js code and compare it with the one that works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. From it, i have managed to see that i am sending stuff with HTTP protocol whereas the successful packets go with HTTP protocol. Now, I am very new to Nodejs... how do i change that code snippet so that it sends my stuff correctly? Also out of interest, how could i send the stuff as a Hex string, just curious

Comment: Thank you very much, i have used that code and sniffed the packets with tcpdump as well. There is a slight difference in what gets sent to the port. I have edited my question to include a screenshot of wireshark whilst analyzing the packets. What causes that difference? i even tried to send the hex string from the successful system but still no joy:

Comment: Add a `console.log` of the data you are sending from Node.js in `client.write` and post this

Comment: I have edited the question and put in the code that i used to indicate the string i am sending and the results from dumping the packets being sent.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Esp:Interface Version="1.0" xmlns:Esp="http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/"><Esp:Admin TerminalId="LINUX001" Action="INIT"><Esp:Register Type="CALLBACK" EventId="DATA_REQUIRED" /><Esp:Register Type="EVENT" EventId="DEBUG_ALL" /></Esp:Admin></Esp:Interface>

Comment: I just tried this and I am not getting the extra two bytes before the payload. Are you sure you are not doing anything else with `client`? You can skip the `TextEncoder` and send directly a string.

Comment: No, I am not doing anything else with client excerpt the code in that snippet. However, with the java system that successfully initializes the terminal, there is a separate "Connect" process that generates a lock file in /var/lock/LCK..ttyS60. Could this be a necessary preparatory step to ensure the terminal initialisation? Perhaps the system only initializes if and only if it has an exclusive lock onto the port ..?

Comment: Wait, sorry, my fault. The good one has extra two bytes, the bad one does not. So it is in fact you that should be sending something in the beginning. The good output has `01 3a` in the beginning - for 314 bytes. Start by sending this. You have to convert `mString.length` to a two byte number in network order yourself - I am not aware of any standard way to do this in Node.js.

Comment: Thanks a million @mmomtchev! Those two bites were the crucial link to getting this to work. I sent the String with those bites preceding it and as raw data as you suggested, Device initialized and replied as expected. Once again, thank you very much

Comment: gyron@gyron-Vostro-5502:~/project/esd_trial$ node test.js
:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Esp:Interface Version="1.0" xmlns:Esp="http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/"><Esp:Admin TerminalId="LINUX001" Action="INIT"><Esp:Register Type="CALLBACK" EventId="DATA_REQUIRED" /><Esp:Register Type="EVENT" EventId="DEBUG_ALL" /></Esp:Admin></Esp:Interface>
connected to server!
<Esp:Admin Action="INIT" ActionCode="APPROVE" MessageReasonCode="9791" TerminalId="LINUX001">

Comment: The rules for those 2 bytes is: **They are the header to indicate the length of the data segment of the message.
If the message length is less than (2^16)-1 or 65535 then a two-byte header will be used.  
The first byte of the header contains the quotient of the length of the message (excluding this header) and 256. The second byte contains the remainder of this division. Both these values are represented in binary as unsigned integer values ranging from 0 to 255 (bytes 0x00 to 0xFF). **. How can I dynamically calculate these bytes and prepend them before sending message?

Comment: `body` is your message. `const message = Buffer.alloc(body.length + 2); message[0] = body.length / 256; message[1] = body.length % 256; message.set(body, 2);`